# Javascript animation without canvas?

Tags: javascript, performance, animation

Is there a considerable difference in the performance between Javascript animation directly on the web page and Javascript animation on the canvas element.

For example, I have one image to moving across the screen. Is it better to draw image on canvas first or just to move it with JavaScript?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think this should help better http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-smoother-animations-transitions-browser

Answer (score 1):

Canvas has potential to be significantly faster because it's built for rendering

Comment: This is correct. But I think for the sake of moving a single image across the screen, one could use `translate` css3 property and do it with javascript. It's very easy and it should be performant enough, as modern browsers will utilize GPU to make sure transitions are smooth.

Comment: Actualy, I have a few elements to move. So, the canvas would be better in my case?